How simple addition operation performed with just one instruction by BitBitJump?
According this:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-instruction_set_computer
Its instruction has 3 operands, the meaning is: copy the bit addressed by a to the bit addressed by b and jump to the address c.
So, how do addition works by only one instruction?
I tried to figure out
High Level Instruction:
x = 6 (0110)
y = 9 (1001)
z = a + b (1111)

Low Level Instruction:
x[0] = 0
...
???


The BitBitJump paper explicitly gives a detailed explanation of designing basic operations, including addition (ref. Section 7).

@codeR I have read partially, is it possible that the BitBitJump works on computer with word size 2-bit?
